# Count number of occurances of pairs of values that are in different order in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an R dataframe with two columns

```
    data <- data.frame(
Process1 = c("A","B","C"),
Process2 = c("B","A","E")
    )
```

In the context I am working in, the pairs `A-B`  and `B-A` are considered the same.
How can I count the number of occurances of each value pair, without `A-B` and `B-A` pairs counted as different values?

The expected output would be

| Process_pair | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| A-B | 2 |
| C-E | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my solution based on your example. If your real problem is more complex, this solution would need some changes:

```
data$index <- apply(data, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "-"))

table(data$index)
```

Comment: This works fine with my real data as well. Could you provide how this would look if there were more than two columns in the df?

Comment: This solution will work for n columns, because it assumes that you will use all the columns in your `data.frame` to define the `index`. However, if you have some column that you do NOT want to consider, you have to make some changes inside the `apply` function. Let me know if this is the case so I can update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Process_pair = if_else(
    Process1 > Process2, 
    true = paste(Process2, Process1, sep = "-"), 
    false = paste(Process1, Process2, sep = "-")
  )) %>%
  count(Process_pair)
```